# java.security.AccessControlException in applet communicating with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, applet, noclassdeffounderror

My school's programming club is starting a tutoring program, and I have built a Java applet that students can use to request sessions. The applet communicates with a database that has a table that stores the availability of the tutors, and shows the user the available times.

First off: I know it's a bad idea to have an applet communicate directly with a database, for security reasons. That being said, this is a fairly low-risk situation (nothing "sensitive" is stored on the database), and this solution is only temporary (we don't currently have a server capable of running tomcat, so everything needs to be done client-side).

The applet GUI loads correctly, but throws a `java.security.AccessControlException ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")` exception when it initializes the class that tries to access the database, and no data is loaded. How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I've changed my code so that the DB communications occur on the same thread as the GUI. Now I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-46" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:298)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at helpsessions.DBHandler.run(DBHandler.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You probably need to sign the applet. Untrusted applets are sandboxed.

Comment: @bmorris591 Should not be necessary to sign the applet, so long as the web and database servers are on the machine, and the JDBC driver is sensible.

Comment: So `NoClassDefFoundError`.. did you not suspect that we will need to see the run-time class-path of the applet in order to help solve that?  I could have said that yesterday, but was hoping you would get the idea from a bit of searching and progress this matter yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applets have a very restricted security model by default, in order to extend the facilities available to the applet you will need to sign the applet, and then write an updated security policy with the extended permissions you require.

Your second problem - class not found - is because the driver is not being distributed with the applet.

I found this with reference to Java 1.1.

> If you're using an applet, then you must place those JARs and class files in the applet's codebase directory and/or archive locations

I'm not sure how relevant is to the latest versions of Java, but I would suggest that is your best option to make the driver Jar available to the applet.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to sign the applet if the database is located on the same server, and the JDBC driver is sensibly written. Error message is about `Thread.setContextClassLoader` which no driver should be using.

Comment: Agreed, but is the DB on the host server, and does it have a type 4 JDBC driver?

Comment: Could this result from the fact that I'm starting a new thread to handle the DB operations? It's my understanding that separating these operations from the GUI thread is a good practice, but perhaps its overcomplicating things here...

Comment: @drewmore4 I would concentrate on getting it to work before worrying about threads.

Comment: @ChrisCooper, yes the db is on the host server. I'm not sure about the type of the driver, but it's called mysql-connector-java-5.1.23

Comment: Looks like threads could be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493206/why-is-the-setcontextclassloader-method-placed-on-thread