# How spring boot change the default classloader use setContextClassLoader?

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader

I searched the Internet, and everybody tell if you use custom classloader, you should explicitly call `loadClass` to load a class.

But I found in spring boot, you can just new a class and the class will load by `LaunchedURLClassLoader`. I check the code in spring-boot-loader found it just use `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader)` in `Launcher`, and I tried this but it doesn't work in my code, why?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493206/why-is-the-setcontextclassloader-method-placed-on-thread

Comment: I know the reason, I made a mistake, when I load the MainClass like spring boot, I just called the `super.findClass` in my custom classloader, so the MainClass is loaded by the AppClassloader, every code called by the MainClass will also load by AppClassloader, so my custom classloader didin't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader)
```

This is designed to work with standard JARs. Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-classloader-and-class-override